# Registering to NavigationService to Prevent NavigateAway (Save Changes)

Tags: c#, wpf, navigation

I want to prevent a user from navigating away from a page should I detect that there are changes they have not yet saved.

I tried using the `Unloaded` method on the `Page` but I believe that is already too late and I could not use `e.Cancel = true` to prevent navigation.

I saw some questions similar already and they suggested subscribing to the `NavigationService.Navigate` event and preventing navigation through here. I tried to access it using `var nav = new NavigationService.GetNavigationService(this);` but I know this is incorrect.

Basically I cannot find an explanation on how subscribe to and prevent the `NavigationService` navigating.

Comment: Why try and prevent it? why not implement an IsDirty pattern on your properties and when this returns true ask the user if he still wants to navigate. This way you will never hit the navigation in the first place.

Comment: @SilentStorm that is essentially what I want to do - I'm just unsure of how to ask the user before the navigation occurs (for example they close the program or click on a new page).

Answer (score 0):

You could implement the IConfirmNavigationRequest interface on your VM

```
public void ConfirmNavigationRequest(NavigationContext navigationContext, Action<bool> continuationCallback)
    {
        if (VM.HasChanges)
        {
            continuationCallback(false);
        }
        else
            continuationCallback(true);
    }
```

But this also depends how are you navigating to your views. Are you using VIEW discovery or View injection?
If you are using the PRISM Navigation service to manage your navigation **(i.e. using RegionManager.RequestNavigate() function)** then the above approach is good.

Comment: I'm just using `NavigationService.Navigate` to navigate to pages hosted inside a `NavigationFrame`.